# How do I get the return code from a stored procedure in Toad?

Tags: sap-ase, toad

I have a test procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE bfmsp_testproc(@test CHAR(32) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
  IF @test IS NULL
    RETURN

  IF @test = 'BadReturnCode'
    RETURN 1

  /* Bad test, should probably do something */
  PRINT 'Invalid test code'
  RETURN 1
END
```

However, I cannot get the return code when I run it in Toad for Sybase.

```
bfmsp_testproc

bfmsp_testproc 'invalid'

bfmsp_testproc 'BadReturnCode'
```

There are no results sets (obviously).  I see the PRINT output in the Messages tab of the results.  However, I cannot find the return code anywhere in the output.  The return code is available in my application code, so I know it is coming from Sybase OK.

Ideas?  Is there a setting somewhere I am missing to show this?  Or does Toad lack this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Adaptive Server 12.5 or greater.

```
DECLARE @ret_val INT
EXECUTE @ret_val=bfmsp_testproc 'BadReturnCode'
SELECT @ret_val
```